# Tortoise SVN Merging committed revisions in same repository

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, revisions

I'm trying to clean up my repository. Since I'm committing my changes very often, to be sure, I have many changes that were committed seperately but belong together.
Is it possible to join multiple committed revisions (in the same repository) in the revision log?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the straight answer is no, but this is a workaround:

1. Manually put together the commit comments from your desired range
2. Make a copy of the updated repository
3. Revert to the latest revision before your desired range
4. Merge that revision to HEAD (Read the "Undoing changes" section in [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) for more info)
5. Commit your copy from step 2 and insert the comments

Comment: I was afraid so. I'm going to try that if there's really no other way. thx